# Anything in here that would escape string (PHP)

Tags: php

```
$_GET['search'] = ucfirst(strtolower(str_replace("_"," ",urldecode($_GET['search']))));
```

For some reason it's adding slashes into the string similar to mysqL_escape_string, anyone got any ideas what would be causing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have most probably **[`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc)** set to `on` in `php.ini`. If you want to avoid that, make a check like this:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
   $mytext = stripslashes($your_text);
}

// and your further code....
```

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if magic_quotes_gpc is enabled on your server. If this is enabled, PHP automatically escapes anything from _GET _POST or _COOKIES.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) is turned on. You can get the setting with [`get_magic_quotes_gpc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php).